# I am trying to have my "multible label widget" as well as my "creating buttons" but when when i get one to work the other does not

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

Here is the code that i have scripted i know it looks bad i am a total noob at this but i really need help. I want my GUI to show the "welcome" and "this gui was written by..." message at the bottom and then add the  button functions that i am later going to intergrate with a api.

```
from cProfile import label
from tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()
def create_label():
# creating multible label widgets
    myLabel1= Label(root,text="Welcome")
    myLabel2= Label(root,text="       ")
    myLabel3= Label(root,text="       ")
    myLabel4= Label(root,text="       ")
    myLabel5= Label(root,text="This Gui was written by Seha")

    # Showing it on the screen and putting it in rows and columns
    myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=10)
    myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=10)
    myLabel4.grid(row=2, column=10)
    myLabel3.grid(row=3, column=10)
    myLabel5.grid(row=4, column=10)
    create_label.pack()

def create_button():
# Creating buttons
    myButton= Button(root, text="Click on this button to check floor price for a specific collection: ",command=label)
    myButton2= Button(root, text="Click on this button to check the 24h volume for a specific collection:", command=label)
    myButton.pack()
    myButton2.pack()



root.mainloop()


This is what my code looks like and i screenshotted what the gui shows
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJnxu.png
```

Comment: Your code will just show a blank window because `create_label()` and `create_button()` have never been executed.

Comment: Why do you have this line `create_label.pack()` inside `create_label()`? You cannot `pack()` a function.  Also `grid()` is used inside `create_label()`, but `pack()` is used inside `create_button()`.  `grid()` and `pack()` cannot be used together inside same container.